# Alternative to CASE Statement to Compare and Summarize Data

Tags: sql

I have a database that looks like the following;

```
--------------------------------
region | price_a | price_b
--------------------------------
USA    |  100    |  120
USA    |  150    |  150
Canada |  300    |  300
Mexico |   20    |  25
```

I need to compare the values from each price column and count the matched and mismatched prices and summarize as follows:

Required Results

```
--------------------------------
region | price_match | price_mismatch
--------------------------------
USA    |    1        |    1
Canada |    1        |    0
Mexico |    0        |    1
```

I can do this via multiple case statements (below) but I'm wondering if there is a better approach.

Current Code:

```
SELECT
    region,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN price_a = price_b THEN 'match' END) AS price_match,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN price_a != price_b THEN 'match' END) AS price_mismatch
FROM
    FOO
GROUP BY region;
```

Comment: What you have may not be the shortest approach, but it is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks Phil,I tend to agree. I'm happy to see the answers below. which I wouldn't have thought of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing from your recent questions, you're using Snowflake, in which case you can use a more compact syntax. I still think using `case expression` is better from a documentation and portability standpoint;

```
select region, 
       sum(iff(price_a=price_b,1,0)) price_match,
       sum(iff(price_a=price_b,0,1)) price_mismatch
from cte
group by region;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum`:

```
select region, sum(price_a = price_b), sum(price_a != price_b) 
from foo 
group by region
```